# PouchDB and extra fields for attachments

Tags: pouchdb

The following appears to be the fields that PouchDB adds for each attachment (data is also stored but not displayed in the pouch inspector).

```
    "_attachments": {
     "2957E559-57E3-40F2-84D3-8A90318E8D4E.jpg": {
     "digest": "md5-Oz3iYrGNkq+ElwofiTENiQ==",
     "content_type": "image/jpeg",
     "length": 49066,
     "revpos": 6,
     "stub": true
     },
```

Is there a way to add any other fields? One field that would be useful would be a date field. I store images on the server and one of the fields is the date inserted. It would be useful to be able to take the date from server and put it in the local database.

But there doesn't appear to be a way to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to add extra fields to attachments.  You can, of course, add as many fields as you want to a document, so you could create additional fields that correspond to attachments.  Example:

```
{
    "_id": "some document",
    "_attachments": {
        "2957E559-57E3-40F2-84D3-8A90318E8D4E.jpg": {
            "digest": "md5-Oz3iYrGNkq+ElwofiTENiQ==",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "length": 49066,
            "revpos": 6,
            "stub": true
        },
    },
    "attachment-meta": {
        "2957E559-57E3-40F2-84D3-8A90318E8D4E.jpg": {
            "date": "2017-01-01 00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea.  I actually have an images database where only images are in it with an ID that points back to another database.  There's no reason I couldn't add a non attachment record to the file since the database is not a defined database.  Thanks.